# Upload npm dependencies to a server

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I need some help with the following situation:

At the moment I am working with Maven and Spring in order to do a web application. My team was working downloading the dependencies for different frameworks, but now I want to use npm to make the dependencies managment easier.

When I run npm install it downloads the dependencies locally, but the idea is not to upload the node_modules folder to git or the web, is to have the package.json file and download them manually in each computer. 
I know that the app is compressed in a war file (I don't know when and how, when I started working here that was working like that), and when is compressed it downloads the maven dependencies (or that is what I understood). I want to make the same with the npm dependencies, the idea is to configure somewhere that it has to run npm install before compressing the whole application.

Does anyone know how to do that? I hope that you could get the idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for war packaging Maven war plugin is used - you cannot invoke npm command from it.

> Note: When using the war: goals it is assumed that the compile phase is already done. The WAR Plugin is not responsible for compiling the java sources or copying the resources.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

As workaround for endpoint you can install required modules by `npm install -g` if your server have the access to npm repo. Otherwise you need to copy `node-modules` manually.

Don't forget about the permissions.

Comment: How can I know if the server has access to npm repo? It depends on the server? In case that it has, where do I have to write the command "npm install -g"? 
In case that it has no access, when I download the node_modules folder sometimes download with the specific root in my computer, and that might not work on the server. Is there anyway to automatically change it to a relative location?
Thank you!

Comment: `-g` will do the installation of packages globally on the npm instance. so they will be available globally despite `node-modules` will be missing. but if versions or dependencies will change inside your project - it will not be automatically installed on server side. should be run same way as `npm install` along side `package.json`

Comment: what do you mean with gloabally? It will look for the package.json automatically? I couldn't understand that. If I update the versions in package.json won't be updated on the server side? What is the useful part of node if that does not work like that? Thank you and sorry for these kind of questions!

Comment: to fix the permissions: `chown -R user:usergroup node-modules` use sudo prefix if needed )

Comment: versions in package.json won't be updated on the server side? - no. if you whant some automation - use GULP and update-module plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-update-modul

Comment: well, I've just been noticed that it seems that the servers are private, so I don't think that they have access to npm server. But if I want to upload the node_modules folder to the server, some dependencies inside have inside its package.json things like "C:\\Users\\Motomine\\Documents\\Repositories\\Project\\src\\main\\webapp\\resources", this is not ok, it has to have a relative location. Is there any way to change this? Thank you!

Comment: then use `gulp-watch` + `gulp-typescript` + your script for fixing those. Gulp will monitor file for xhanges and then running the fix-script against it.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! I'm now trying to skip those absolutes locations that I don't know how to do it. I tried with gulp but I might be missing something because is not working. Is there any easier way? Because gulp-watch downloads **a lot** of dependencies that I prefer not to upload.

Comment: scheduled bash script? )

Comment: I don't understand that, how can I do it?